# reactJs secure storage

Tags: reactjs, security, local-storage, client-side

I'm a back-end developer who has to create the front-end too in the current project!
I'm using reactJs and I know that for authorizing users I should get an `api_token` from my back-end API then use the `api_token` in the next requests! so I should store the `api_token` (actually somewhere into the client's browser)! but where should I store it to be secure?

the first answer came to my mind was 'Local Storage' ! but I've read this article: [Don't store tokens in local storage](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/store-tokens#don-t-store-tokens-in-local-storage)

I've searched and found [@auth0/auth0-spa-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/auth0-spa-js), but I don't know can I trust this package (and similar) or not?

these are the way's which I've found! but what's the correct way to store sensitive data like this?

Comment: Storing token in cookie is better solution. react-native-secure-storage is react-native package won't  work for the web application.

Answer (score 0):

The Auth Flow should be on the Web should be

1. Send User/Password Details to server
2. Server validates and returns encrypted token with some details inside and that's stored as a HTTP Cookie
3. Setup Protected endpoints so only users with token can access them

Security : HTTP Cookie only means that the browser doesn't have access to it on the client, only the server. But someone can simply just Copy Paste it into their cookies which if you're worried about or working on sensitive stuff, you will need to implement additional security measures such as the ones mentioned.
Generally, Device Management is not a web concern but you can also some validation on the token for things like make the token expire in 5 minutes, or expire on session end, DeviceId, Browser Id, IP address, send them an email that a new unknown IP has logged in, etc.

Answer (score -2):

## Never store private tokens in your frontend code

You should create a server that can only be accessed from a particular url (the url of your app). This server can have the secret tokens that you need to make calls. The that server can forward requests to the services you will use that need private tokens.

Comment: I cant understand! would you please explain more